# FuelPHP: extra columns in a Many-to-Many connecting table possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, many-to-many, fuelphp

Let's say I have a table called "people" which is filled with many people. I also have a table called `drinks` which is filled with different drinks.

I want to associate the people in the "people" table with various "drinks" they order.

Of course, many people can order many different drinks, including the same drink that someone else ordered, thus I assume meriting a many-to-many relationship.

However, I also want to include the sequential *order* that each person ordered their drinks in. I'm thinking that this should also go into the many-to-many connecting table with "person_id" and "drink_id", but I'm wondering if this is proper database structure or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason not to do this. Your through table can contain extra columns to provide meta information about the relation. The only restriction in fuelphp is that you would have to have a 3rd model between `people` and `drinks` to be able to access the extra information via models.

Eg: where `drink_people` is the through table.

`'people' has many 'drink_people'
'drink_people' has one 'drink', has one 'people'
'drink' has one 'drink_people'`

Comment: Wouldn't it be drink has many drink_people? Because many people could order the same drink.

Comment: Has many then, my mistake. The actual relation types you should choose to fit your needs, but the idea stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can have both at the same time, a many_many for directly accessing the related objects, and a one-to-many with the through table to access the relation data.

Only downside at the moment is that this means two queries, because accessing the many_many will not create an object for the relation record.